# How to map nested array to the second attribute in the array in ruby

Tags: ruby

Sorry for the poor title, I just don't know how to express what I want here without examples.

I have the following

```
[
  [ [1,2], true ],
  [ [3,4], false ]
]
```

and I want to get

```
[
  [1, true],
  [2, true],
  [3, false],
  [4, false]
]
```

Is there any clean way to do this in ruby?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I edited with the fix

Comment: Another variation on a theme: `arr.flat_map { |(x,y), bool| [[x,bool], [y,bool]] }`. Notice that all the answers reproduce the array in your example. Had you assigned a variable to it  (`arr = [[[1, 2], true], [[3, 4], false]]`) that would not have been necessary. For that reason it is advised to assign a variable to all inputs in examples given in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `flat_map` on the outer array and `map` on the inner array. Something like:

```
arr = [
  [ [1,2], true ],
  [ [4,5], false ]
]

arr.flat_map do |nums, val|
  nums.map {|num| [num, val]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
arr = [
  [ [1,2], true ],
  [ [3,4], false ]
].flat_map { |(arr, bool)| arr.product([bool]) }
# [[1, true], [2, true], [3, false], [4, false]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
ary =
  [
    [[1, 2], true],
    [[3, 4], false]
  ]

ary.each_with_object([]) do |(nums, boolean), new_ary|
  nums.each { |num| new_ary << [num, boolean] }
end

# => [[1, true], [2, true], [3, false], [4, false]]
```